# vb.net thread with loop not working in Windows 8.1 but works in Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, gps, windows-8.1

I am working on a Windows form application to communicate with a GPS which has been built in Visual Basic 2010 express. I have tested it with Windows 7 using an external GPS connected by bluetooth and it works fine but i am having problems on windows 8.1.

The particular element being tested at present outputs NMEA sentences from the GPS into a textbox. The previous test version passed the unprocessed packet to the text box without issue on both windows 7 and 8.1

The next test was to split the individual sentences and add them one by one to the textbox which involves looping through an array of the sentences. 
This second test works fine with on the windows 7 laptop but not on the windows 8.1 tablet. When run in Windows 8.1 the text never appears in the textbox however when other events happen such as changing a combo box on the form a sentence will load and if i keep changing the combo then the textbox will update each time. Also if i add a msgbox into the loop, the textbox will update each time the msgbox is closed.

I have installed Visual Basic Express 2013 on the Windows 8.1 tablet and when placing a stop in the loop on the command for the textbox it appears that it is not stuck and keeps looping through, though the textbox does not update on the form.
The only other issue i can see is that on the windows 7 PC the i see the following output message:

> The thread '' (0x2e04) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Whilst on the windows 8 i encounter:

> The thread '' (0x149c) has exited with code 259 (0x103)

I am not sure whether this code 259 points to the issue with the thread.

Below is the main section of code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class frmCommInit
    Public GPSsettings As New GPSsetting
    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallBack(ByVal [text] As String) 'Delegate added to provent threading areas during data recieval

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        cboPorts.Items.AddRange(myPort)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        RecievedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub

    Private Sub RecievedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        Dim NMEASentances() As String = Split(text, vbCrLf)
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        If Me.rtbOutput.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf RecievedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.rtbOutput.Text = text & vbCr & Me.rtbOutput.Text
            For i = 0 To NMEASentances.Length - 1
                l = NMEASentances(i).Length
                If l > 10 Then
                    If NMEASentances(i)(0) = "$" And NMEASentances(i)(l - 3) = "*" Then
                        Me.rtbOutput.Text = NMEASentances(i) & vbCr & Me.rtbOutput.Text
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not sure why it worked perfectly in windows 7 but not windows 8.1 but i have found that adding two System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) after the else and before then end of the sub has fixed the problem, though I am considering moving this code to a background worker.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class frmCommInit
    Public GPSsettings As New GPSsetting
    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallBack(ByVal [text] As String) 'Delegate added to provent threading areas during data recieval

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        cboPorts.Items.AddRange(myPort)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        RecievedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub

    Private Sub RecievedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        Dim NMEASentances() As String = Split(text, vbCrLf)
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        If Me.rtbOutput.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf RecievedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Me.rtbOutput.Text = text & vbCr & Me.rtbOutput.Text
            For i = 0 To NMEASentances.Length - 1
                l = NMEASentances(i).Length
                If l > 10 Then
                    If NMEASentances(i)(0) = "$" And NMEASentances(i)(l - 3) = "*" Then
                        Me.rtbOutput.Text = NMEASentances(i) & vbCr & Me.rtbOutput.Text
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End Sub
End Class
```